# Realm Object relationships using typescript

Tags: typescript, realm

I am implementing a realm model. (similar as discussed here: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1795).

```
class Artist {
    // [index: string]: any;
    public static schema: Realm.ObjectSchema = {
            name: 'Artist',
            primaryKey: 'identifier',
            properties: {
                name:  'string',
                identifier: 'string',
                albums: 'Album[]',
            }
    };

    public name: string;
    public identifier: string;

    constructor(name: string, identifier: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.identifier = identifier;
    }

    public hasAlbum(album: Album): boolean {
        const filteredAlbums: Realm.Results<Album> = this.albums.filtered("identifier == $0", album.identifier);
        return filteredAlbums.length > 0;
    }
};
```

This works fine in typescript as I just need to declare the variables and their type.
The issue starts with declaring object relationships such as:

```
properties: {
    albums: 'Album[]'
}
```

In the Realm schema. This tells Realm that we want a list of Albums (which also is a Model).
Now I need to tell typescript that my class has a property called Albums.

1. Option: As an array

```js
public albums: Album[];
```

The downside to this is that I can't use Realm.Results' methods such as filtered or others. Also I'd need to initialise the array with a value technically overwriting what comes back from the database.

2. Option: As Realm.Results

```js
public albums: Realm.Results<Album>;
```

The issue here is that I must give it a value either directly or in the constructor. I can't give it a value really (nor does an empty results construct exist).

3. Option: Adding an index signature (removing the property declaration)

I could add: [index: string]: any; to my class which let's me do all sorts of operations.
And doing this raises the question why I should be using typescript if it does not warn me about type safety because I turned it off.

Does anybody know an idea on how I can declare properties in typescript "without initialising" them and using them inside my class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After searching for this exact problem a couple of minutes ago, I think I figured it out.

For your particular use, you would type it like so

```
public albums: Realm.List<Album & Realm.Object>;
```

Now I get the expected intellisense type hints. Realm.Object seems necessary because if you only return a single element. It would only have the type Album and we could not work with it as a Realm.Object.